# How do the lines of lw add and sw translate to the chart below?

Tags: mips, machine-code

I'm just getting started learning this material. I don't understand where the 35, 9, 8 and such numbers in the chart come from. All I see in the assembly lines is the number 300.

https://ibb.co/ZYrk42H

Answer (score 0):

35 is the opcode for `lw`, 9 is the actual register number for `$t1` and 8 is the actual register number for `$t0`.

`$t0` is a friendly register name — see [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MIPS_Assembly/Register_File), you can see that `$t0` is also `$8` (aka register number 8).  As you can imagine, the hardware doesn't care about the friendly names, and only wants to see the actual numbers.

35 is the opcode, as you can see [here](https://www.assemblylanguagetuts.com/mips-instruction-set-opcodes-reference-sheet/), `lw` has opcode `100011`, which is 35